# Join in PySpark joins None values

Tags: python, join, apache-spark, null, pyspark

In PySpark I want to make a full outer join of two RDDs with key-values pairs where keys may be `None`.
For example:

```
rdd1 = sc.parallelize([(None, "a"), (None, "b")])
rdd2 = sc.parallelize([(None, "c"), (None, "d")])
join_rdd = rdd1.join(rdd2)
```

It looks like that PySpark joins the records where keys are None:

```
print(rdd1.join(rdd2).take(10))
>>> [(None, ('a', 'c')), (None, ('a', 'd')), (None, ('b', 'c')), (None, ('b', 'd'))]
```

However, in SQL when I join two tables:

```
Table1:    Table2:
key   val   key   val
NULL  a     NULL  c
NULL  b     NULL  d

SELECT * FROM Table1 JOIN Table2 ON Table1.key = Table2.key
```

I have an empty result set.

I suppose that this is because in Python `None == None` is true and in SQL `NULL = NULL` is false.

I have two questions:

1. Is there a way to emulate SQL behaviour and force PySpark not to join by Nones?
2. Is is a bug or feature? As SQL user I've expected that joining by null keys returns nothing. I am new in PySpark and found nothing in documentation about joinig Nones. Maybe it's worth to make some note in Spark Programming Guide?

Or am I wrong somewhere?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your expectations are wrong. RDD API doesn't follow SQL semantics and was never intended to. `RDD.join` is simply a hash based linking with a [`portable_hash`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/branch-1.6/python/pyspark/rdd.py#L61https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/branch-1.6/python/pyspark/rdd.py#L61) which is designed to provide meaningful `None` hashing in the first place.

If you want SQL-like semantics you should use Spark SQL / Data Frames:

```
schema = StructType([
  StructField("_1", IntegerType(), True), StructField("_2", StringType(), False)
])

df1 = sqlContext.createDataFrame(rdd1, schema)
df2 = sqlContext.createDataFrame(rdd2, schema)
df1.join(df2, ["_1"])
```

If you want to achieve similar result on RDDs you filter out `None` keys before `join`:

```
rdd1.filter(lambda x: x[0] is not None).join(rdd2)
```